# Wildcards when SpringData + QueryDSL + OracleDB

Tags: java, spring-data, querydsl

I would like to make DSL Queries with wildcards. The default Wildcard character for Oracle is '%'. But what if I would like to change this default Character to '*'. So what if I would like to make DSL Queries like `'Rzeszot*'` instead of `'Rzeszot%'`.

Of course I could make something like `name.replaceAll('\\*', '%')` what works, but my question is if there is any QueryDSL syntax (http://www.querydsl.com/) which makes this 'replacement' automatically 'on the fly'?

Comment: "*The default wildcard character for Oracle is '%'*" - That's the wildcard character for the query language **SQL** defined in the SQL standard - it's nothing special to Oracle.

Comment: Yes but you can use QueryDSL with Mongo where wildcard char is '*'. This is what I meant.